# Small probabilities in Python

Tags: python, random, coin-flipping

How accurate is Python's random() function?

Assume I'd like to make a decision based on a `1 / 234276901` probability coin flip, can I still use a

```
if random() < 1. / 234276901:
```

statement?

How accurate would such statement be? (in terms of the actual probability the if will be taken).

Is there a more precise (yet running in reasonable time) way to get such coin flips?

Comment: `random()` returns a *float* in the range [0.0 and 1.0), not an integer. Floating point has definite limitations. Use `random.randint()` (only in Python 3) if you need that large a number of different states.

Comment: What do you mean by accuracy? And you surely wouldn't use that since random returns something between 0 and 1, so it would always be true.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - you are obviously correct, I wrote that in a haste since I had to leave. I've edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random.random()` produces a float value in the range [0.0, 1.0) (meaning that `0.0` is included in the possible values, but `1.0` is not).

Floating point numbers have 53 bits of precision, so you get 2 ** 53 different 'steps' between 0.0 and 1.0. 53 bits is plenty of precision to represent `1 / 234276901`, which only needs about 28 bits:

```
>>> 234276901 .bit_length()
28
```

So yes, using `random.random() < 1 / 234276901` will work, there is plenty of precision left over.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. Small correction:  range -> [0.0, 1.0) and not [0.0, 0.1).

Comment: @RB: yup, that's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a coin flip of 1 / 234276901, use `random.random()` like this:

```
>>> floor(random.random() * 234276901)
```

since `random()` gives real values between 0 and 1, we should multiply it by your max to stretch the interval than rounding values to convert them to integers.

---

You can also use `random.randint()`:

```
>>> random.randint(1,234276901)
```